python dataflow : GroupByKey cannot be applied to an unbounded PCollection with global windowing and a default trigger
I have a simple python dataflow code that uses unbounded pcollection  . It just

Reads from pubsub
Parse into json with output tags SUCCESS and FAILURE
Validate json  with output tags SUCCESS and FAILURE. It just yields
elements with    FAILED tags if validation is incorrect , otherwise
it   yield the    element as SUCCESS
Prints the success tags

Here is the sample code
         | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=str(user_options.input_sub))
         #  | 'WindowIntoFixedWindows' >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(60), trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(60)), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
         #  | "Window into Fixed Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(GlobalWindows(),trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(AfterCount(10), AfterProcessingTime(10))),  accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
         | 'Parse into JSON' >> ParDo(functions.parse_into_json).with_outputs(FAILED_TAG, main=SUCCESS_TAG))
        
# Validate successful json records
validated_data = (items[SUCCESS_TAG]
      | 'Validate Raw Product JSON Data' >> ParDo(functions.validate_product_data).with_outputs(FAILED_TAG, main=SUCCESS_TAG))
  # # Persist successful json records in BQ as raw
   (validated_data[SUCCESS_TAG]
            | "Print each line " >> beam.Map(print))

It works successfully  when I run this code locally . Here is the command I use to run locally
python3 product_pubsub_to_bq_to_crs_dataflow.py --staging_location gs://SOMEBUCKET-dataflow1/stage --temp_location gs://SOMEBUCKET-dataflow1/temp --project SOME_GCP_PROJECT --region us-central1 --streaming --input_sub projects/SOME_GCP_PROJECT/subscriptions/sub-for-prd --bq_raw_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_raw --bq_raw_failure_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_raw_failed --bq_curated_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_curated --bq_curated_failure_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.incr_prd_failed --crs_branch 0 --crs_project SOME_GCP_PROJECT --setup_file ./src/setup.py

When I run this on dataflow, it always fails with this error
ValueError: GroupByKey cannot be applied to an unbounded PCollection with global windowing and a default trigger

On this line
 (validated_data[SUCCESS_TAG]


Here is the command I use to run on dataflow
gcloud dataflow flex-template run incr-prd-pubsub-to-bq-to-crs --template-file-gcs-location gs://SOME_BUCKET-dataflow1/templates/prd_raw_gcs_to_bq.json --additional-experiments enable_prime --enable-streaming-engine --region us-central1 --network default --service-account-email SOME_GCP_PROJ_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --subnetwork https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/SOME_GCP_PROJECT/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default --parameters input_sub=projects/SOME_GCP_PROJECT/subscriptions/sub-for-prd --parameters bq_raw_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_raw --parameters bq_raw_failure_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_raw_failed --parameters bq_curated_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.prd_curated --parameters bq_curated_failure_dest_table=SOME_GCP_PROJECT:myds_raw.incr_prd_failed --parameters crs_branch=0 --parameters crs_project=SOME_GCP_PROJECT

I have tried to use FixedWindow with triggers and GlobalWindow with trigger but it keeps failing with same error
I have also added this window step in the pipeline right after reading from pubsub
|'WindowIntoFixedWindows' >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(60), trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(60)), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)

Here example 1 is other topic that explains unbounded collections
Here is a similar issue
But it still fails whenever I try get the tagged output  from the previous step .
validated_data[SUCCESS_TAG]
Most likely it is caused because of tagged output in unbounded collection . Same code works if I don't have unbounded pubsub pcollection in streaming mode, rather just a bounded pcollection in batch .
Here is the example validate function thats simply tags the output
def validate_product_data(self, elem):
        """
        Par Do Function to perform product validations
        """
        #TODO Add all validations here so when we transform later, we don't have to check 
        top_level_keys = elem.keys()
        self.helper.validate_key(elem, 'id', top_level_keys)
        self.helper.validate_key(elem, 'name', top_level_keys)
        self.helper.validate_key(elem, 'brand', top_level_keys)
        if FAILED_REASON in elem.keys():
            yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput(FAILED_TAG, elem)
        else:
            yield elem

Here is a screen shot of the original code without windows that still failed


There are 3 places where streaming is specified
During build
gcloud dataflow flex-template build ${DF_PRODUCT_PUBSUB_TO_BQ_TO_CRS_TEMPLATE_LOCATION} \
--image-gcr-path "${GCR_HOSTNAME}/${GCR_PROJECT_ID}/${DATAFLOW_IMAGE_REPO}/${DF_PRODUCT_PUBSUB_TO_BQ_TO_CRS_IMAGE_NAME}:latest" \
--additional-experiments "use_network_tags_for_flex_templates=${NETWORK_TAG}" \
--enable-streaming-engine \

In the code
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

During run
gcloud dataflow flex-template run ${DF_INCR_PRODUCT_PUBSUB_TO_BQ_TO_CRS_JOB_NAME}-${prefix} \
--template-file-gcs-location ${DF_PRODUCT_PUBSUB_TO_BQ_TO_CRS_TEMPLATE_LOCATION} \
--additional-experiments enable_prime \
--enable-streaming-engine \


If I keep it during build,  keep it in the code and keep it during
run , it always fails no matter what

If I remove it during build , but keep it in the code and during run
, it works just fine

If I remove during build, remove it from the code, but keep it during
run , it fails

If I remove during build, keep it he code, remove it during run , it
works just fine too


So apparently using it during build is causing this issue . Windowing is not needed
